# Is there a way to convert regular sliding closet doors to mirror ones?

Tags: closet, mirror

I have a regular sliding closet door, which I would like to replace with a mirror one. But I'm wondering whether there's a way to buy 'add-on' mirrors for the existing doors and just mount them. (And whether that's cheaper obviously.) Maybe I'm searching using wrong keywords, but I can't seem to find a solution.

[image]

Comment: I'd check IKEA first. If they have them, it'd be easier to just replace. You can get a mirror and mount it but a) mirrors can be pricey and b) heavy...and these are likely hollow core doors so might make it difficult to mount.

Comment: Agreed, you may run into a problem of what the tracks are rated for as glass mirrors may be significantly more mass than they will comfortably service.

Comment: Doors plus track probably won't cost noticeably more than replacement doors that might not work with this track...